# How to position a div to the right of headline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to add an `<img>` (an orange circle) to the right of my headline `<h2>`. the problem is that when i shrink the screen the circle jumps above the headline. How can i make it stay on the right side no matter the size of the screen?

```css
.head-text {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 12%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: auto;
}
img {
  margin: 10 0 0px 0px;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: black;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" data-menuanchor="thirdPage">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="main mainupp">
      <div class="myheader border"></div>
      <div class="head-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-2">
            <div class="post-thumb orange"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-8">
            <h2><img>ASDASD</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: position: absolute; should do the trick but at one point it will float over the text.

Answer (score 1):

`white-space: nowrap` prevents it from breaking into 2 lines and if you want to keep it pretty (instead of overlapping the text), you can also add `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` to the `h2`:

```css
.head-text {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 12%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: auto;
}
img {
  margin: 10 0 0px 0px;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: black;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" data-menuanchor="thirdPage">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="main mainupp">
      <div class="myheader border"></div>
      <div class="head-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-2">
            <div class="post-thumb orange"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-8">
            <h2><img>ASDASDASDASDASDASDASDASD</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position`ing in this case:

```css
img {
  margin: 10 0 0px 0px;
  /* float: right; Remove this */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  /* Add these */
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

That should fix. Do not remove the `position: relative` on the `.head-text`.

**Updated Snippet**

```css
.head-text {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 12%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: auto;
}
img {
  margin: 10 0 0px 0px;
  /* float: right; Remove this */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  /* Add these */
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: black;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" data-menuanchor="thirdPage">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="main mainupp">
      <div class="myheader border"></div>
      <div class="head-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-2">
            <div class="post-thumb orange"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-8">
            <h2><img>ASDASD</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And please, nest the tags properly.